# Find R, L and C in RLC series circuit given voltage over capacitor and current through inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, laplace-transform, linear

I have a couple of exercises in my textbook (Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 6th edition) that look like the following:
[image: exercise from ee book]

To solve this problem, my first idea was to transform it into the laplace domain, and then use that \$i=C\tfrac{dv}{dt}\$ to solve for C. But that didn't give me an equation that simplified to a number and I assume it's also wrong because I'm not taking the initial conditions into account?

The solutions manual in my textbook does it with the following method.

1. They setup the equation for a series RLC circuit, and they add the initial conditions.
2. They simplified it in a weird way which isn't correct as they are missing a factor of division by s.
3. They solve for the roots of s which is weird as some terms get divided by 0 and not all s terms are in one part of the equation?
4. Lastly they add another equation they get from the i=c*dv/dt which I understand how they arrive to.

I'd like to have a little bit more explanation on steps 2 and 3 above as I'm not sure if it is a correct approach? Thanks!
[image: solution]

Comment: Very nice exercise ... I like it.

Comment: Indeed, there are a couple like these and I think this is the type of exercise that could help me broaden my circuit analysis knowledge if i were to understand it.

Comment: @TomCajot Just skimming this... Isn't the specification for iL(t) in **mA**? But in their solution they say at t=0 that iL(0)=20 **A**? The units don't seem to match. What am I missing?

Comment: @periblepsis, this solution manual is full of mistakes so I just wanted to know if their method worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution for this overdamped circuit:

[image]

$$
\begin{cases}
 v_c(t) = (30-10e^{-20t}+30e^{-10t})u(t)& \space V \qquad{[1]}\\
\\
 i_L(t) = (0.04e^{-20t}- 0.06e^{-10t})u(t)& \space A \qquad{[2]}
\end{cases}
$$

Then:

$$
\begin{cases}
 v_c(0_-) = 50\space{V} \\
 i_L(0_-) = -0.02\space{A} \\
 v_c(\infty) = 30\space{V} \\
 i_L(\infty ) = 0\space{A}
\end{cases}
$$

$$\boxed{V_i = v_c(\infty) = 30\space{V}}$$

$$
\begin{align}
 &i_c(t)=i_L(t) = C\frac{dv_c(t)}{dt}= C(200e^{-20t}-300e^{-10t})u(t) \\
 &i_c(0_+)=i_L(0_-) = -100C
\end{align}
$$

So

$$\boxed{C=200 \space\mu F}$$

On the other hand

$$
\begin{align}
  v_L(t)= L\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}=L(-0.8e^{-20t}+0.6e^{-10t})u(t)  &\qquad{[3]}\\
  v_L(0_+)=-0.2L &\qquad{[4]}
\end{align}
$$

But, \$v_L(0_+)\$ can be also calculated applying KVL at \$t = 0\$:

$$
\begin{align} 
  v_L(0_+)&=-50+30-R(-0.02) \\
  v_L(0_+)& = -20+0.02R \qquad{[5]} 
\end{align}
$$

Equating \$[4]\$ and \$[5]\$:

$$ L+0.1R=100 \qquad[6] $$

Another equation relating \$R\$ and \$L\$ can be obtained choosing other point in time. For instance, doing \$t=0.1s\$ in \$[1]\$, \$[2]\$ and \$[3]\$, respectively:

$$
\begin{align} 
  v_c(0.1)&=39.68 \space V \\
  i_L(0.1)& = -0.0167 \space A \\
  v_L(0.1)&=0.1125L \qquad{[7]}
\end{align}
$$

But, \$v_L(0.1)\$ can be also calculated applying KVL at \$t=0.1s\$:

$$
\begin{align}
 v_L(0.1)&=-39.68+30-R(-0.0167) \\
 v_L(0.1)&=0.0167R-9.68 \qquad{[8]}
\end{align}
$$

Equating \$[7]\$ and \$[8]\$:

$$ L-0.148R=-86.04\qquad[9] $$

Solving \$[6]\$ along \$[9]\$:

$$ \boxed{R=750 \space \Omega} $$

$$ \boxed{L=25 \space H} $$

----------------------------- **EDIT** ---------------------------

Regarding your comment:

Yes. It seems to be fine. A differential equation describing the natural response for \$v_c(t)\$ is:

$$\frac{d^2v_c(t)}{dt^2}+\frac{R}{L}\frac{dv_c(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{LC}v_c(t)=0$$

The corresponding characteristic equation is:

$$ s^2+\frac{R}{L}s+\frac{1}{LC}=0 $$

Or:

$$ (s-s_1)(s-s_2) = 0 $$

Therefore, for an overdamped second order system with two real distintic roots (characteristic modes), \$s_1\$ and \$s_2\$:

$$
\begin{cases}
s_1&=-\frac{R}{2L}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\frac{R}{L})^2-\frac{4}{LC}}=-10 \\
\\
s_2&=-\frac{R}{2L}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\frac{R}{L})^2-\frac{4}{LC}}=-20
\end{cases}
$$

$$ (s + 10)(s+20) = 0 $$

The complete response for a step input (\$V_iu(t)\$) and a overdamped system (\$\xi>1\$) has the form below:

$$v_c(t)=(V_i+A_1e^{s_1t}+A_2e^{s_2t})u(t)$$

where the values of constants \$A_1\$ and \$A_2\$ are determined from the initial conditions.

From here, follow the reference you presented.

Comment: Just one *slippery* part to the above. As \$v_c\left(t\to\infty\right)=30\:\text{V}\$ I agree that \$v_i\left(t\to\infty\right)=30\:\text{V}\$. But I don't see evidence that \$v_i^{\:'}\left(t\right)=0\$ for all \$t\ge 0\$. So I'm not sure it requires (without more work to show the fact) that \$v_i\left(t\right)=30\:\text{V}\$ for all \$t\ge 0\$. You claim it. But I think there's some added work to prove it. Also, \$v_C^{\:'}\left(0\right)\cdot C = i_L\left(0\right)\$. So \$C=\frac{i_L\left(0\right)}{v_C^{\:'}\left(0\right)}=200\:\mu\text{F}\$. Agree there.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I'd also like to know if the method they use is valid?